# Tag [roles] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: sec

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

Currently have this:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
     <sec:username/><br/>
     <sec:roles/><br/>
      <g:link controller="logout" action="index">Logout</g:link>
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
    <h1>Who are you?</h1><br/>
    <g:link controller="login" action="auth">LOGIN</g:link>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

Which gives the error:

```
Tag [roles] does not exist.   No tag library found for namespace: sec
```

However when I remove `<sec:roles/><br/>` it works fine.  Why is this?  This is only a problem in production, on intellij everything is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tag `roles` exists in spring security core plugin. If you want to show user roles in the view then you can create your own tag.

```
class TestTagLib {

    static final namespace = 'myTag'
    def springSecurityService

    def userAuthorities = { attrs ->
        out << springSecurityService.principal.authorities 
        //or out << springSecurityService.authentication.authorities
    }
}
```

and use it in you view as

```
<myTag:userAuthorities/>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib) for the spring security core Grails plugin, there is no tag "roles". That's why it errors. Intellij likely just ignores this tag completely.